# Attempting to run prop.test in R. Created new variables, cannot get prop.test statement to run

Tags: r, statistics

I created a new variable to see if a team accumulated 100 or more points. Then I separated the data into East and West conferences. I need to test if the real proportion of the teams to score 100 or more points in the East conference is different from the the West conference. I have to provide a confidence interval on the real difference in the teams scoring over 100 points with a significance level of 0.10.  When I run my code, I am getting errors and I am not sure what I have done wrong.

My code functions properly up until the prop.test statement.

**My Code:**

```
library(readxl)
NHL1819 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Desktop/Statistics/NHL1819.xlsx")
View(NHL1819)

NHL1819$hunpts <- ifelse(NHL1819$PTS >= 100, 1, 0)

eastern <- NHL1819[(which(NHL1819$Conference == "Eastern")), ]
western <- NHL1819[(which(NHL1819$Conference == "Western")), ]

prop.test(c(length(which(eastern$hunpts = 1)), length(which(western$hunpts = 1))),
  c(nrow(eastern), nrow(western)), conf. level = .90)
```

**Error log:**

> library(readxl)
>   NHL1819 <- read_excel("C:/Users/TLeeps/Desktop/Statistics/NHL1819.xlsx")
>   View(NHL1819)
>
> NHL1819$hunpts <- ifelse(NHL1819$PTS >= 100, 1, 0)
>
> eastern <- NHL1819[(which(NHL1819$Conference == "Eastern")), ]
>   western <- NHL1819[(which(NHL1819$Conference == "Western")), ]
>
> prop.test(c(length(which(eastern$hunpts = 1)), length(which(western$hunpts = 1))),
>   Error: unexpected '=' in "prop.test(c(length(which(eastern$hunpts ="
>     c(nrow(eastern), nrow(western)), conf. level = .90)
>   Error: unexpected ',' in "  c(nrow(eastern), nrow(western)),"

**DPUT**

```
dput(NHL1819)
structure(list(Team = c("Tampa Bay Lightning", "Boston Bruins", 
"Toronto Maple Leafs", "Montreal Canadiens", "Florida Panthers", 
"Buffalo Sabres", "Detroit Red Wings", "Ottawa Senators", "Washington Capitals", 
"New York Islanders", "Pittsburgh Penguins", "Carolina Hurricanes", 
"Columbus Blue Jackets", "Philadelphia Flyers", "New York Rangers", 
"New Jersey Devils", "Nashville Predators", "Winnipeg Jets", 
"St. Louis Blues", "Dallas Stars", "Colorado Avalanche", "Chicago Blackhawks", 
"Minnesota Wild", "Calgary Flames", "San Jose Sharks", "Vegas Golden Knights", 
"Arizona Coyotes", "Vancouver Canucks", "Anaheim Ducks", "Edmonton Oilers", 
"Los Angeles Kings"), Conference = c("Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", 
"Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", 
"Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", "Eastern", 
"Eastern", "Western", "Western", "Western", "Western", "Western", 
"Western", "Western", "Western", "Western", "Western", "Western", 
"Western", "Western", "Western", "Western"), Division = c("Atlantic", 
"Atlantic", "Atlantic", "Atlantic", "Atlantic", "Atlantic", "Atlantic", 
"Atlantic", "Metropolitan", "Metropolitan", "Metropolitan", "Metropolitan", 
"Metropolitan", "Metropolitan", "Metropolitan", "Metropolitan", 
"Central", "Central", "Central", "Central", "Central", "Central", 
"Central", "Pacific", "Pacific", "Pacific", "Pacific", "Pacific", 
"Pacific", "Pacific", "Pacific"), GP = c(82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 
82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 
82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82), W = c(62, 49, 46, 44, 
36, 33, 32, 29, 48, 48, 44, 46, 47, 37, 32, 31, 47, 47, 45, 43, 
38, 36, 37, 50, 46, 43, 39, 35, 35, 35, 31), L = c(16, 24, 28, 
30, 32, 39, 40, 47, 26, 27, 26, 29, 31, 37, 36, 41, 29, 30, 28, 
32, 30, 34, 36, 25, 27, 32, 35, 36, 37, 38, 42), OTL = c(4, 9, 
8, 8, 14, 10, 10, 6, 8, 7, 12, 7, 4, 8, 14, 10, 6, 5, 9, 7, 14, 
12, 9, 7, 9, 7, 8, 11, 10, 9, 9), PTS = c(128, 107, 100, 96, 
86, 76, 74, 64, 104, 103, 100, 99, 98, 82, 78, 72, 100, 99, 99, 
93, 90, 84, 83, 107, 101, 93, 86, 81, 80, 79, 71), ROW = c(56, 
47, 46, 41, 33, 28, 29, 29, 44, 43, 42, 44, 45, 34, 26, 28, 43, 
45, 42, 42, 36, 33, 36, 50, 46, 40, 35, 29, 32, 32, 28), SOW = c(6, 
2, 0, 3, 3, 5, 3, 0, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3), SOL = c(1, 3, 2, 0, 7, 3, 5, 1, 1, 
5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 6, 3, 3, 
4), GF = c(325, 259, 286, 249, 267, 226, 227, 242, 278, 228, 
273, 245, 258, 244, 227, 222, 240, 272, 247, 210, 260, 270, 211, 
289, 289, 249, 213, 225, 199, 232, 202), GA = c(222, 215, 251, 
236, 280, 271, 277, 302, 249, 196, 241, 223, 232, 281, 272, 275, 
214, 244, 223, 202, 246, 292, 237, 227, 261, 230, 223, 254, 251, 
274, 263), DIFF = c(103, 44, 35, 13, -13, -45, -50, -60, 29, 
32, 32, 22, 26, -37, -45, -53, 26, 28, 24, 8, 14, -22, -26, 62, 
28, 19, -10, -29, -52, -42, -61), hunpts = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Team", "Conference", "Division", "GP", 
"W", "L", "OTL", "PTS", "ROW", "SOW", "SOL", "GF", "GA", "DIFF", 
"hunpts"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a syntax errors:

prop.test(c(length(which(eastern$hunpts == 1)), length(which(western$hunpts == 1))),
  c(nrow(eastern), nrow(western)), conf.level = .90)